# jQuery to retreve data when checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jquery-selectors

Instead of using a table, I have the following HTML showing a checkbox in col 1, a name in col 2, and an EMail address in col 3. The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="rowLight">
<div class="select"><input name="checkbox" id="chk1" class="chktbl" type="checkbox"></div>
<div class="name">Mary</div><div class="emayl">Mary@ABC.com</div>
</div>
<div class="rowDeep">
<div class="select"><input name="checkbox" id="chk2" class="chktbl" type="checkbox"></div>
<div class="name">Jerry</div><div class="emayl">Jerry@ABC.net</div>
</div>
```

I need to iterate through each checkbox, and it the box is checked, capture the name & Email address that will be sent to a webservice which will populate an EMail table.  I tried something like this, but need help...

```
var vals = [];
$('.select input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(i) {
var name = $(this).next('.name');
vals.push(($(name).html());
var emayl = $(this).next('.emayl');
vals.push(($(emayl).html()); });
```

Thanx,
Jerry

Comment: is `.rowLight` & `.rowDeep` an alternating DIV symbolizing rows?

Comment: What help exactly do you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this could work:

```
var data = $(".select input:checkbox:checked").map(function() {
    var $parent = $(this).closest(".select");
    return {
        name: $parent.next(".name").text(),
        email: $parent.siblings(".emayl").text()
    };
}).get();
```

Note that the data will look like:

```
[ { name: '<name>', email: '<email>' }, ... ]
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/rMPDH/

---

If you truly want the data in just an array:

```
["<name1>", "<email1>", "<name2>", "<email2>"]
```

You could try:

```
var data = $(".select input:checkbox:checked").map(function() {
    var $parent = $(this).closest(".select");

    return [ $parent.next(".name").text(), $parent.siblings(".emayl").text() ];
}).get();
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/4GdC8/

---

**Notes:**

- Using the handy [`.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map) to take a jQuery result and transform it into the data you need.
- Calling `.get()` at the end of the `.map` call forces the resulting object into a proper array (as opposed to a jQuery object)
- Uses [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest), [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next), and [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings) to retrieve the proper data.

Comment: Andrew - I'd like to send the 'data' object to my PageMethod for processing. What type of object should I define it as in my PageMethod?  Something like: Public Shared Function wsGetEMails(ByVal data As ________) As String

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with ASP.NET, but I'd try to make the array containing objects that have `name` and `email` properties work. Just a guess, but it could be that you define an object with those properties, and then accept an array of those objects in your method.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternatvie solution, using `rowDeep` and `rowLight` to symbolize rows

```
$('.rowLight,.rowDeep').each(function(i,e){
    var $row = $(e);

    // see if the checkbox is checked
    if ($row.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')){
        var name = $row.find('.name').text(),
            emayl = $row.find('.emayl').text();

        alert(name + ' <' + emayl + '>');
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EPrUc/)

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle out, Open your browser javascript console i.e either Chrome or firebug in firefox. http://jsfiddle.net/q2jsp/12/

depending on the version of jquery you can use either siblings() or next().next().